# form that uses a query as data source doesn't permit inputs

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access form, that uses a query as the data source.  This query uses 3 different tables.  I would like the form to allow inputs and the input values to populate one of these 3 tables.  Currently the form will not allow the inputs. Please advise
Thanks very much in advance, Nathaniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an updateable query: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html, but if that is not possible, there are other approaches.

If the query joining the three tables is already quite simple, you could consider whether you really need all the tables in one form, for example, a form / subform set-up is a very useful way of presenting and updating data from more than one table. Another possibility is a combobox if one of the tables includes look-up data, such as country code / country.

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the data source, and fetch the data explicitly in the open method. It means a little more VBA code, but it may be less contrived that what you are doing at the moment.

Comment: I completely disagree. An unbound form will lose all the power of MS Access forms.

Comment: But that is not my down vote, this is an option, even if not the one I would choose.